# Alternate to PIVOT in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using oracle sql developer for fetching weekend data. When the query runs on a Monday it would fetch data for the previous weekend.

**This query works**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    select 
        mm.r_number, 
        s.holder,
        trunc(mm.received_date) - TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) as received_date
FROM messages mm
JOIN items s ON (mm.r_number = s.service_num)
WHERE account_number = 12353
AND r_number in ('0000928158','0000927608','0000927610','0000945321')
)
PIVOT
(
COUNT(received_date)
FOR received_date in (1 as Sunday, 2 as Saturday)
)
ORDER BY r_number
```

**The raw data**

| r_number | s.holder | mm.received_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0000928158 | LVAD EMERGENCY (AH) | 17-MAR-21 |
| 0000928158 | LVAD EMERGENCY (AH) | 16-MAR-21 |
| 0000927610 | RX/PHARMACY | 15-MAR-21 |

**The output is**

[image]

Problem: How do I fetch dates instead of days

Comment: Can you please provide your sample input and expected output?

Comment: You do not; a `PIVOT` has to have fixed values so you could pivot on `2020-03-13` as it is a static value but you can't pivot on the date from last Saturday as it changes from week-to-week.

Comment: MTO- thank you for your response. How do I achieve the same results in sql without pivoting

Comment: You ask multiple questions: title says *"Alternate to PIVOT"*; last phrase says *"How do I fetch dates instead of days"*; and in comments it is again *"How do I achieve the same results in sql without pivoting"*. Please stick to one question only.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use dynamic SQL in a PL/SQL block. Something like:

```
DECLARE
  strSaturday_column   VARCHAR2(30) := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  strSunday_column     VARCHAR2(30) := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  rc                   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  nR_number            NUMBER;
  strHolder            VARCHAR2(2000);
  nSaturday            NUMBER;
  nSunday              NUMBER;
  tab                  CHAR(1) := CHR(9);
BEGIN
  OPEN rc FOR
   'SELECT R_NUMBER, HOLDER, SATURDAY AS ' || strSaturday_column ||
   '       SUNDAY AS ' || strSunday_column ||
   '  FROM (SELECT *
              FROM (select mm.r_number, 
                           s.holder,
                           trunc(mm.received_date) - TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) as received_date
                      FROM messages mm
                      JOIN items 
                        ON (mm.r_number = s.service_num)
                      WHERE account_number = 12353 AND
                            r_number in ('0000928158','0000927608','0000927610','0000945321'))
              PIVOT (COUNT(received_date)
                     FOR received_date in (1 as Sunday, 2 as Saturday)))
      ORDER BY r_number';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('R_NUMBER' || tab || 'HOLDER' || tab ||
                       strSaturday_column || tab || strSunday_column);
  LOOP
    FETCH rc
      INTO nR_number,
           strHolder,
           nSaturday,
           nSunday;
    EXIT WHEN rc%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nR_number || tab || strHolder || tab ||
                         nSaturday || tab || nSunday);
  END LOOP;
END;
```